# android file created not found?

Tags: java, android, file

I'm trying to create a file in android but can't seem to find where is the file. I just copied the exact code from the tutorial but its not working.

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

I tried to look for the file using eclipse's DDMS and windows file explorer but i can't find it anywhere. Am i missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `openFileOutput()` your new file is stored inside internal storage of your app.

It's located under */data/data/**[your_package]**/files*

Access to this location from outside of your app is restricted. You need rooted device or an emulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is working just fine, the file is located in:

```
data/data/<package name>/files
```

Check it with DDMS File Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i can't see anything there. In DDMS, i tried to expand data but i cant.

Comment: You need a rooted device for that, try to run the code in emulator and look into /data/... with DDMS on the emulator.